# Show and hide div with slide left right dynamic

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$("show-div").on("click", function() {
  $("#first-block").hide();
  $("#second-block").hide();
  $('#third-block').animate({
    //    'right': '100px'
  });
  $('#fourth-block').animate({
    //    ' right': '50px'
  });
})
```

```css
.count-block-wrap {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row text-center mx-auto">
  <div class="col-3 col-xl-3" id="first-block">
    <div class="count-block-wrap">
      <div class="figures">
        <span>123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="count-desc">
        <h5>HELLO</h5>
        <p class="mb-0">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-xl-3" id="second-block">
    <div class="count-block-wrap">
      <div class="figures">
        <span>123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="count-desc">
        <h5>HELLO</h5>
        <p class="mb-0">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-xl-3" id="third-block">
    <div class="count-block-wrap">
      <div class="figures">
        <span>123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="count-desc">
        <h5>HELLO</h5>
        <p class="mb-0">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-xl-3" id="fourth-block">
    <div class="count-block-wrap">
      <div class="figures">
        <span>123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="count-desc">
        <h5>HELLO</h5>
        <p class="mb-0">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onClick="show-div()">Click Me</button>
```

I have four `div`s. On the click of a button I want to hide the first two (sliding from right to left) and show the last two (sliding from left to right).

Comment: Please show us your Html and show what you have tried to create this effect yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

`$("#show-div").on("click", function() {...})`

instead of

`$("show-div").on("click", function() {...})`

and

`<button id="show-div">Click Me</button>`

instead of

`<button onClick="show-div()">Click Me</button>`

like this:

```js
$("#show-div").on("click", function() {
  $("#first-block").hide();
  $("#second-block").hide();
  $('#third-block').animate({
   'right': '100px'
  });
  $('#fourth-block').animate({
    'right': '50px'
  });
})
```

```css
.count-block-wrap {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row text-center mx-auto">
  <div class="col-3 col-xl-3" id="first-block">
    <div class="count-block-wrap">
      <div class="figures">
        <span>123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="count-desc">
        <h5>HELLO</h5>
        <p class="mb-0">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-xl-3" id="second-block">
    <div class="count-block-wrap">
      <div class="figures">
        <span>123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="count-desc">
        <h5>HELLO</h5>
        <p class="mb-0">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-xl-3" id="third-block">
    <div class="count-block-wrap">
      <div class="figures">
        <span>123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="count-desc">
        <h5>HELLO</h5>
        <p class="mb-0">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-xl-3" id="fourth-block">
    <div class="count-block-wrap">
      <div class="figures">
        <span>123</span>
      </div>
      <div class="count-desc">
        <h5>HELLO</h5>
        <p class="mb-0">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="show-div">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: @ChrstianCarrillo yes but can you help me with the expexcted result